# Define CKEditor custom plugin using In-page method, when plugin have more configs itself

Tags: ckeditor

I used a new custom plugin like 'wordcount' in CKEditor like below by using config.js

config.js:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'wordcount';
config.wordcount = {
    wordlimit: '5',
    charlimit: '50'
};
```

As you see, plugin itself have two extra config parameters: 'wordlimit' and 'charlimit'.

It works propely in config.js but for some reasons , i need to define CKEditor configuration in-page, like below:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    extraPlugins:'wordcount'
});
```

But i don't know how to define specific configs for 'wordcount' plugin? i tried something like below, but all of them failed

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    extraPlugins:'wordcount',
    wordlimit: '5',
    charlimit: '50'

});
```

OR

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    extraPlugins:'wordcount',
    wordcount.wordlimit: '5',
    wordcount.charlimit: '50'

});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    extraPlugins:'wordcount',
    wordcount: {
        wordlimit: '5',
        charlimit: '50'
    }
});
```

If it fails I'll remove this answer :)